# ¿Cómo contar el número de operaciones (trading) realizadas en una hoja de cálculo de Excel utilizando una fórmula condicional personalizada?

Tags: excel, binance

## Considere lo siguiente:

Tiene una hoja de cálculo de Excel que contiene el "Historial comercial" de una cuenta comercial particular de "Binance Exchange".

Este archivo ha almacenado la información de manera que usted puede saber cómo una operación en particular se `"LLENÓ"`, lo que significa que una operación de un `SIDE` específico debe tener otra operación `SIDE` **opuesta**, por lo que

- Si la primera operación para un símbolo en particular tenía `BUY` como `SIDE` inicial (Entrada), entonces la última operación para ese símbolo en particular debe tener `SELL` como el `SIDE` final (Salida).
- De manera similar, si la primera operación tenía `SELL` como `SIDE` inicial (Entrada), la última operación debe tener `BUY` como `SIDE` final (Salida).

Sin embargo, hay algunas cosas complicadas en esta hoja de cálculo, aquí hay una muestra:

| Date(UTC) | Symbol | Side |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-27 10:39:45 | GALBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:39:44 | GALBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:39:44 | GALBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:58 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:24 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:22 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:21 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:22:21 | APEBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:15:00 | MATICBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:14:50 | MATICBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 10:14:48 | MATICBUSD | SELL |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:55:06 | MATICBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:51:38 | APEBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:43:42 | GALBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:43:34 | GALBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:43:33 | GALBUSD | BUY |
| 2022-09-27 09:43:32 | GALBUSD | BUY |

Como se puede observar, el historial de operaciones se ordena desde la última hasta la primera realizada, se puede suponer que:

- Todas las operaciones se 'LLENARON' por completo (por cada entrada realizada, se realiza una salida)
- Cualquier símbolo podría haber sido comercializado ***nuevamente*** más tarde.
- La cantidad de operaciones de un lado no es necesariamente igual a la cantidad de operaciones del lado opuesto, por ejemplo, en la imagen de arriba, la primera operación para 'APEBUSD' inmediatamente 'LLENÓ' la orden mientras que su operación de salida se distribuyó en 5 órdenes `SELL`.

¿Cómo podría adaptarse la función de Excel `COUNTIF` para estimar la cantidad total de operaciones realizadas?

En la imagen de arriba, suponiendo que no hubiera más datos, la cantidad total de intercambios sería **3**, este **3** lo calculo de la siguiente forma:

> El primer registro de un símbolo con un side específico y el último
> registro con un side opuesto cuentan como 1, entonces al haber 3 pares
> , bajo esas condiciones, serían 3 trades realizadas.

Comment: no bastaria con contar evitando duplicados??

Comment: No porque podrían omitirse otras operaciones hechas sobre el mismo par tiempo después a la primera que se hizo en este. @ArcanisGK507

Comment: entonces no entiendo como obtienes ese 3 ...

Comment: necesitas enumerar y ordenar los criterios para que llegue a ese 3 ...

Comment: Claro mira, el `3` lo calculo de la siguiente forma: El **primer registro** de un símbolo con un side específico y el **último registro** con un side opuesto cuentan como `1`, entonces al haber 3 pares distintos, bajo esas condiciones, serían 3 trades realizadas @ArcanisGK507

Comment: que es un side específico??

Comment: que es un  side opuesto?

Comment: haber 3 pares distintos, cuales son los 3 pares distintos?

Comment: que se consideran trades?

Comment: recuerda que nosotros no conocemos los conceptos que estas empleando en tu excel ...

Comment: De acuerdo, seré más específico: El `SIDE` es el tipo de operación hecha, en los mercados financieros se conocen como `BUY` y `SELL`, es decir cuando realizas una operación a `LARGO` y a `CORTO` respectivamente. El `SIDE` opuesto simplemente sería la operación de salida que haces para asegurar ganancias, naturalmente sí tu entras a `LARGO` para salir debes hacer una operación contraria, es decir vender poner una orden de venta (`SELL`) y esperar a que se llene, lo mismo ocurren sí entras a `CORTO`, para salir debes poner una orden de compra (`BUY`) y esperar a que se llene.

Comment: agrega eso a la publicacion

Comment: igual no te estoy entendiedo nada XD

Comment: Una trade debe ser considerada aquella en la que tú como tal entraste y saliste, es decir pusiste una orden (`BUY` o `SELL`) y una vez llenada completamente pusiste otra orden de *SIDE opuesta* (`SELL` o `BUY`). Así tu puedes saber sí eso que hiciste generó ganancias o pérdidas después de haberte salido.

Comment: Los 3 pares distintos son: **GALBUSD**, **APEBUSD**, **MATICBUSD**

Comment: te soy soincero, con el ultimo comentario sigo pensando que se resuelve contando los registro unicos / menos los duplicados... no hay un escenario en donde tengas que uno de estos: GALBUSD, APEBUSD, MATICBUSD termine valiendo 2 o 3 ... y el resultado del conteo sea un 5...

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en Binance Futures, a veces por la falta de liquidez, tu orden no se llena inmediatamente sino que se distribuye en otras órdenes pequeñas, y por eso es que ves que hay varios registros de varias operaciones hechas con el mismo `SIDE` para el mismo símbolo, pero en realidad es una sóla operación, entonces sería incorrecto contarlas como varias cuando en realidad siempre ha sido una sola, que en conjunto con su opuesta, generan una sola trade. @ArcanisGK507

Comment: entonces solo cuentas las llenas?

Comment: Sí @ArcanisGK507

Comment: entonces tienes que usar una condicion if para validar que este llena...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestamente, no se me ocurre ninguna manera de hacerlo en una única fórmula, pero sí con un cuadro resumen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna de `Symbol` solo la puedes automatizar si tienes Excel365 con la fórmula `=UNICOS(B2:B22)`. Si tus datos cambian frecuentemente de tamaño y no tienes Excel 365 tendrás que crear la lista a mano (copias y pegas y luego quitar duplicados, se tardan segundos) o lo automatizas con VBA.

Bien, la siguiente fórmula vale en cualquier versión de Excel. La celda I2 tiene la siguiente fórmula:

```
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($B$2:$B$22;$H2;$C$2:$C$22;I$1)
```

Esta formula la arrastras manualmente hasta la celda J2 y luego arrastras hasta abajo. Cuenta cuantas operaciones de tipo SELL/BUY hay por cada SYMBOL.Por ejemplo, hay 3 filas SELL de GALBUSD.

La lógica aquí es que el número de pares **completo** será el número más bajo de los dos tipos de Side. Es decir, por ejemplo GALBUSD tiene 3 SELL y 4 BUY. Pares **completos** (es decir, que puedas emparejar un SELL con un BUY) solamente hay 3, uno de los BUY se queda sin pareja.

La columna de PAIRS es la que simplemente señala con un 1 si existe par o no. La fórmula es:

```
=MIN(1;I2:J2)
```

Y arrastras hacia abajo.

Extraes el valor más bajo entre el número 1 y el recuento de operaciones SELL/BUY de cada símbolo. La lógica es simple. Recuerda que, como se explicó anteriormente, el número más pequeño de las 2 columnas anteriores  significaba la cantidad de **pares completos** que existen. Pues extraemos el número más pequeño entre 1 y la cantidad de pares completos. ¿Por qué 1? Porque tú, una vez que haya pares completos, lo cuentas como 1, independientemente de si tienes 1, 3 o 25000. Quieres que cuente como 1, por eso el mínimo. Si no existen pares completos, al menos una de las dos columnas anteriores será 0, con lo que esta formula devolverá 0 en vez de 1, porque no existe ningún par completo para ese Symbol.

Luego simplemente sumas abajo del todo y listo.

Desglosado está chupado pero no he hallado la manera de una sola fórmula. Sinceramente, creo que es mejor así porque con un solo vistazo tienes lo que quieres y además tienes localizados que símbolos no tienen par completo, o cuantos pares completos existen de cada símbolo.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¡Wow! Muy buen enfoque el de tu solución y los detalles de la misma, te lo agradezco, mi duda está resuelta.